# Retrieve file sent through post request in c++

Tags: c++, file, post, httprequest

I'm setting up a micro-service for a cpp application, and i need to send a post request with a file as a parameter from a js project to the cpp one through this micro-service, i've been able to send the post request but i can't retrieve the file.

I've tried to use "http_response.extract-string/json" but it doesn't work, the result is empty

```
void MicroserviceController::handlePost(http_request message) {
    std::cout<< "handlePost(http_request message) " << std::endl;
    std::cout<< message.to_string() << std::endl;    
    std::cout<< message.extract_json().get() << std::endl;   
    std::ofstream o("hello.json");
    o << message.extract_json().get()<< std::endl;
```

after running that, i got an empty hello file.
I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, i just have a lack in http_request methods .
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The function you show is incomplete, and you don't seem to be writing anything to the file. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have done all these before don't worry ! , it is indeed the whole function, or at least where i'm getting a problem, the last line is where i'm writing on the file as you can see,but i guess the extract_json method isn't the most appropriate one, so the question would be what would you have done instead in that line to retrieve the file from the http_request variable "message".

Comment: You're outputting the result of `extract_json()` to the console, are you seeing any result there? If you are seeing the result you need, is `extract_json()` a const function? If not then it may be editing your data before the next call. If you're not getting a result in the console, I'd suggest using a debugger and breaking on that function and investigating the contents of `message`.

Comment: @TheBeardedQuack thanks for your answer, i'm not seeing any result in the console for extract_json, i'll try to debug as you said and i'll let you know

Comment: so the "message.to_string" display on console shows me this :                    `POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
cache-control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 65
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:3000
Postman-Token: 1cb050c0-2af6-4d31-b7dd-5a80979d8575
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.1`                                                               looks like the message.extract_json is empty :/